# Change specific UILabel on specific UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nstimer

I'm building an application in which I click a button and it runs an NSTimer in a label in the selected cell. I'm using one prototype cell and in it I have two labels: the Name and the Time. These labels both have their own tags: 1010 and 1020, respectively. The photo below is what it would look like at runtime. Basically, what I'm looking for is to start a timer in the selected cell. I can't seem to do this without having the timer run in every cell.

**Important:** The prototype cells in the photo are for example ONLY. In my project, I am only using one (1) prototype cell with one (1) identifier.

Thank you for taking the time to read this and if you would like me to provide more information to help you answer the question, I'd be more than happy to do so!

**Edit:** At runtime, ten (10) cells are displayed. NSArrays are populating the data.

**Edit 2:** The problem I keep getting is that the timer goes in every cell. I'm trying to figure out how to target a specific cell. I have stored the cell number. What can I do with that?
[image]

```
int cellNumber;
bool isCurrentlyRunning = NO;

- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
//Table Data Code
self.peopleArray = @[@"Person 1", @"Person 2", @"Person 3", @"Person 4", @"Person 5", @"Person 6", @"Person 7", @"Person 8", @"Person 9", @"Person 10"];
self.TimeArray = @[@"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00", @"0:00"];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.peopleArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleIdentifier"];

    UILabel *lblName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1010];
    UILabel *lblTime = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1020];

    NSString *Name, *Time;

    Name = [self.roundOrder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    lblTime.text = [self formattedTime:self.currentTimeInSeconds];
    lblName.text = Name;

    return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [_myTimer invalidate];
    self.currentTimeInSeconds = 0;
    cellNumber = [indexPath row];
}

- (int)timeToStop{
    int retVal = 0;
    switch (cellNumber) {
        case 0:
            retVal = 100;
        break;
        default:
            retVal = 200;
        break;
    }
    return retVal;
}
- (NSTimer *)createTimer {
    return [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                            target:self
                                          selector:@selector(timerTicked:)
                                          userInfo:nil
                                           repeats:YES];
}
- (NSString *)formattedTime:(int)totalSeconds
{

    int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", minutes, seconds];
}
- (void)timerTicked:(NSTimer *)timer {

    _currentTimeInSeconds++;
    if (self.currentTimeInSeconds == [self timeToStop]){
        [_myTimer invalidate];
    }
}
- (IBAction)startCountDown:(id)sender {

    if (!_currentTimeInSeconds) {
        _currentTimeInSeconds = 0 ;
    }
    if (!_myTimer) {
        _myTimer = [self createTimer];
    }
    isCurrentlyRunning = YES;
}
- (IBAction)stopCountDown:(id)sender {

    if(isCurrentlyRunning == YES){
         [_myTimer invalidate];
        isCurrentlyRunning = NO;
    }else{
        if (_myTimer) {
        [_myTimer invalidate];  
    }
        _currentTimeInSeconds = 0;
        self.lblTimer.text = [self formattedTime:_currentTimeInSeconds];
}
```

}

Comment: "I can't seem to do this without having the timer run in every cell." But you don't show what you _are_ doing. I mean, it's obvious in the abstract how to do it, but what you need to do is fix what you are already doing so that it targets a specific label. So why aren't you showing what you're doing, if you want help with it?

Comment: Hey @matt! Sorry about that. I added the necessary code. I thought my question was more of a general one at first but now that I look at it, it is not. It's specific, so I have added code.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. The user taps a cell and... what? To put it another way: you have a method that creates a timer (`createTimer`) but you never call it. You have a method that responds to the timer firing (`timerTicked`) but it makes no change to _anything_ in the table (or in the model). How do you expect _anything_ to happen in your interface? Or, if it _is_ happening, then show the code that makes it happen.

Comment: I have a button that fires the timer...I didn't think that was relevant to my question. Added.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create an array of `NSTimer`s for each row in the table using scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: and provide the `NSIndexPath` in the userInfo parameter. Then when your selector is called you can check if the index path is visible using `indexPathsForVisibleRows` and if so you can get the cell using `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. And then get the label using the tag.

Answer (score -1):

You can use - (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Construct your NSIndexPath with your section 0 and row that you want to update. Then you can access each label.

Answer (score -1):

You need to take a look at

```
-didSelectrowAtIndexPath method.
```

This method would fire everytime you hit a prototype cell according to its index path.

If your cell has individual tags then you can do a check or as all the cells have similar contents that is you are reusing the cells using the identifier, then all you got to do is fire the nstimer for that cell in that method.

go through some examples for the method and i hope this helps